# How to list services/daemons started at boot _and_ check their loading order

Tags: debian, boot, service, init

I want to be sure in what order services are started during boot process in Debian based systems (Debian Squeeze in particular).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In short:

```
ls /etc/rc*.d
```

This shows you what starts at which runlevel, and within each level the order is determined by the number after the letter (K is Kill, S is start).

You can configure what starts at each runlevel with sysv-rc-conf, which is installable with apt.

e.g. on my system apache2 is symlinked in rc5.d as "S20apache2". A link in the same directory with S19 would start before it, something with S21 would start after it.

Further reading:

- http://wiki.debian.org/RunLevel
- http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html#_the_meaning_of_the_runlevel

Comment: Thank you very much but I need to be sure that for instance chilli is started before bind9 but both of them has S21 prefix. I edited particular /etc/init/ files Required-Start: and Required-Stop: section and I've ran update-rc.d for them. Any ideas what could go wrong?

Comment: You probably want insserv rather than update-rc.d. Is Chili a bespoke app or in the Debian repo? If it's a properly made Debian package you shouldn't need to edit its init script, but if it's bespoke try X-Start-Before rather than Required-Start (and then enable with insserv). Link: http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

Comment: OK, thank you. I've learned about insserv and one more thing: "dollar sign, because they are predefined virtual facilities. Otherwise, the names of System V boot scripts, found in /etc/init.d/, should be used, although without a dollar sign or possible .sh extension." And now prefixes are correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 21):

Would *rcconf* and *sysv-rc-conf* utilities help?

```
# aptitude install rcconf sysv-rc-conf
```

Afterwards you can run them by typing `rcconf` or `sysv-rc-conf`.

[image: rcconf]
[image: sysv-rc-conf]

Answer (score 9):

You can list all services and their status with this simple command:

```
service --status-all
```

From the manual:

> *service --status-all* runs all init scripts, in alphabetical order, with
>          the *status* command.  The status is [ + ] for running services, [ - ]
>          for stopped services and [ ? ] for services without a 'status' command.
>          This option only calls status for sysvinit jobs; upstart jobs can be
>          queried in a similar manner with *initctl list.*

Comment: I don't think this addresses the "what order" part of the question.

Comment: and this also does not really tell which one is enabled (start on boot)

Comment: I have scripts that show up in this command, but they aren't started up.

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in `find /etc/rc*.d -name S*`; do basename $i | sed -r 's/^S[0-9]+//'; done | sort | uniq

Sample output:

acpid
anacron
avahi-daemon
boa
bootlogd
bootlogs
bootmisc.sh
checkfs.sh
checkroot-bootclean.sh
checkroot.sh
cryptdisks
cryptdisks-early
dbus
delayed-services
hostname.sh
hwclock.sh
keyboard-setup
killprocs
kmod
lightdm
mountall-bootclean.sh
mountall.sh
mountdevsubfs.sh
mountkernfs.sh
mountnfs-bootclean.sh
mountnfs.sh
mtab.sh
pppd-dns
procps
qemu-kvm
rc.local
rmnologin
rsyslog
single
sleep
stop-bootlogd
stop-bootlogd-single
udev
udev-mtab
x11-common
```

Answer (score 1):

On Debian rcconf should do the trick, just to configure stop/start of already present services.

I use it all the time on Debian Jessie and Wheezy.

Comment: Could you explain a little more how to use the tool you've mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

### systemd

On [distros using systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd#Adoption), [you can control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) the order. You have to use a combination of `Requires` with `Before`/`After`. Due to the parallel and relationships among services, the service start-up order isn't deterministic.

Use [`systemd-analyze plot`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-analyze.html#systemd-analyze%20plot)

```bash
# This command prints an SVG graphic detailing which system services have been started at what time, highlighting the time they spent on initialization.
systemd-analyze plot > startup_order.svg
```

and [`systemd-analyze dot`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-analyze.html#systemd-analyze%20dot%20%5Bpattern...%5D)

```bash
# to generate a graphical dependency tree.
systemd-analyze dot | dot -Tsvg > systemd.svg
```

[Source and more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311440/4970442).